# css not targeting content or targeting wrong content

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, margin, children

I have here a project in which a menu loads with ajax various sections. On my "contact" section I have this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile_style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <section id="content">

    <div id="container">

      <div id="contact" class="sections">
        <div id="artpurchases">
          <p><span>Art purchases :</span>Galerie Hélène Nougaro</br>
          <a href="mailto:helnougaro@gmail.com">helnougaro@gmail.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div id="otherenquiries">
          <p><span>Other enquiries :</span></br>
          <a href="mailto:cavapaslatet@gmail.com">cavapaslatet@gmail.com</p></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- end of content -->

    </section> <!-- end of container -->

  </body>
```

The general styling of paragraphs for the whole site is like so:

```
p {
    color: #818181;
    font-family: Eagle-Light;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.21em;}
```

And on my contacts section I have this styling:

```
#contact {
    position: relative;}


#contact.sections p {
    margin-bottom: 0;

    display: block;
    text-align: center;}


#contact a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I am trying something so simple as to get some more margin before the "other enquires" line.

When I try to target my second paragraph like so:

```
#contact.sections p:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

nothing happens. I tried to investigate a little bit and this:

```
#contact.sections p:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
}
```

Will return this unexpected result:

[image]

What on earth is happening here? My html is clearly organised with two p tags and they are not as the css is targeting them. Is this a css bug? Thanks

EDIT------------------------------------------------------------------------

html updated:

```
 <div id="contact" class="sections">

          <p><span>Art purchases :</span>Galerie Hélène Nougaro<br>
          <a href="mailto:helnougaro@gmail.com">helnougaro@gmail.com</a></p>

          <p><span>Other enquiries :</span><br>
          <a href="mailto:cavapaslatet@gmail.com">cavapaslatet@gmail.com</a></p>

      </div>
```

Comment: BTW, your `</br>`s should be `<br />` or `<br>`

Comment: Your `</a>`s should also be inside of the `</p>`s

Comment: `:nth-child` targets the children of a common parent element. Your `p` elements do not have a common parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, as you're targeting the childs wrong.

```css
#contact.sections div:nth-child(2) p {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

The reason this did not work for you is that your HTML is wrong. I've corrected the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile_style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <section id="content">

    <div id="container">

      <div id="contact" class="sections">
        <div id="artpurchases">
          <p><span>Art purchases :</span><br>Galerie Hélène Nougaro<br>
          <a href="mailto:helnougaro@gmail.com">helnougaro@gmail.com</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="otherenquiries">
          <p><span>Other enquiries :</span><br>
          <a href="mailto:cavapaslatet@gmail.com">cavapaslatet@gmail.com</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- end of content -->

    </section> <!-- end of container -->

  </body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv1nqd4f/2/)

Comment: HI, thanks for your contribution. This is not working either. It targets nothing and when I change the child to (1) it targets everything.

Comment: @Paul I forgot a `div` between `#contact.sections` and the `:nth-child(2)`

Comment: Thanks again. This doesn't work either. It targets nothing at all regardless of the child

Comment: I'll investigate a little bit, gimee a sec

Comment: @Paul [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/zv1nqd4f/2/) probably being the fact that your HTML is wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately this still doesn't work. I have updated my html as you said to make sure my p tags are children of the same div and corrected the br tags but it still targets them wrong. See edit]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151787/discussion-between-oliver-ni-and-paul).

Comment: OK thanks give me 15 min as I have to get charger for laptop

Answer (score 0):

Just use this selector to target that line

```
#otherenquiries p {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

(with your original HTML, that is)

or even simply

```
#otherenquiries {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```